# How can I use Bumblebee and QtCreator together?

Tags: linux, qt-creator, nvidia

How can I use Bumblebee and QtCreator together without starting QtCreator in Bumblebee?

**For those who don't know what bumblebee is:**

*It is an unoffical version of Nvidia Optimus in Linux. It allows you to activate your dGPU only when you need it. But if you are a graphics programmer you probably want to create your OpenGL context with your dGPU.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.) Create your project.

2.) Go to your project debug folder, in my example `/home/maik/untitled-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_GCC_64bit-Debug`

3.) create a new file. Call it `optimus.sh`

4.) Open optimus.sh and write the following -> `optirun ./untitled`

*Note that untitled is just name of your executable in your debug folder, in my case it is "untitled"*

5.) Go to QtCreator -> `Projects` -> `Build & Run` -> Select your kit that you want to use -> Go to `Run` -> Under `'Run'` click on `'Add'` -> `Custom executable` -> Under `'Command'` , select your `optirun.sh` file -> Turn on `Run in Teminal` .

Now every time you click run in QtCreator, your executable will be started with optirun. Now your dGPU only gets activated if you run your application, instead of being activated the entire time.

Comment: I've tried this, but QtCreator/gdb doesn't stop on breakpoints. Does it stop for you?

Answer (score 1):

The other answer worked, but I feel like my way is cleaner:

- In Qt Creator, go to the `Projects` tab.
- Go to  `Build & Run` -> `[your kit]` -> `Run`.
- On the right hand side, under `Run`, click to add a `Custom executable`.
- In `Executable` fill in `/usr/bin/optirun` (or whatever output `which optirun` gives).
- In `Command line arguments` fill in `./foobar` if your executable is named `foobar` and resides in the build directory.
- Keep `Working directory` as `%{buildDir}`.